# How do I reset my phone without losing everything?

Tags: sd-card

I have an Alcatel Dawn phone and it's lagging and turning on and off. I want to reset it but I will lose my photos and contacts. I don't have an SD card. I don't know which one I should buy or where I can get one for my phone. It didn't come in the box with the phone. How do I reset my phone without losing everything since I don't have on SD card?

Comment: The phone has an internal storage, right? Or where would your photos be stored right now? Just connect to PC and copy them off the device. As for contacts, the contacts app will offer a way to export them to storage.

Answer (score 0):

This part I have done successfully. Unless you are planning to change accounts, you do not have to do anything with your contacts. A a safety net, you can Export them from Gmail on a computer by going into Contacts, Selecting All (Top box with a checkbox) and selecting *Export* from the *More* menu. This will let you even import than into a new account.

Images are even easier to deal with. When you connect your phone to a computer via USB cable, a device or drive (depending on the OS) will appear and you can go into the DCIM folder and copy its contents onto your computer.

After your phone is reset, you can copy back the content of DCIM into the new empty DCIM folder of the phone. Logging in to the same account will retrieve your contacts from Google. If not, you can use the export file (obtained as above) and import them back. If this does not automatically happen on your phone, go into settings and enable Sync for Contacts.